# How to submit form with input file using ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

When i send the `<input type='file' src='D:/.../image.png'>`'s src throught Ajax to views.py in the views the `src` is not correct, It appears like `D:/fakepath/imag.png` the `fakepath` is some security thing made by browser But how I can upload the form's content when I can't get the path of the file input?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set your enctyoe to multipart/form-data
In django you'll find your files under request.FILES, the easiest way to submit the form is to pass the data with js formdata object, it basically takes the entire form and adds it to your ajax request so you can handle it in django like a regular form

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of sending formdata through ajax ?